How to Prove "if $\Omega$ is finite then, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$".
I have just started learning probability and I struggling to prove a result. I have detailed my thoughts below:
An experiment occurred and $\Omega$ is the sample space.
The probability distribution is the function $$ \Bbb{P} : \mathcal{F} \to \Bbb{R} $$ which satisfies the following three axioms:
(i) Let $ A \subseteq \Omega $. $0 \le \Bbb{P}(A) \le 1.$
(ii) $\Bbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\Bbb{P}(\Omega) = 1.$
(iii) For the pairwise disjoint events $A_1, A_2, A_3 \dots, \ 
\Bbb{P}( \displaystyle\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i ) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(A_i).$

I wanted to know the precise definition of $\mathcal{F}$.
My textbook states that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. A $\sigma$-algebra is a set of sets which has the following properties:
(a) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$.
(b) if $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$.
(c) if $A_1, A_2, A_3 \dots \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in \mathcal{F}$.

I have been told that if $\Omega$ is finite, then the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ equals the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. I am struggling to prove this.
I know that I need to show $\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
Proof:
$\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega):$
$\mathcal{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$. Thus, $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
$\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \subseteq \mathcal{F}:$
I have only managed to show the following:
(1) Observe that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under complements, $\emptyset^c = \Omega \in \mathcal{F}$.
I do not know how to show that $\forall A \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega), A \in \mathcal{F}$.
(2) $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra:
i. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
ii. $\forall \ A \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega), A^c \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
iii. For $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots , A_n \in \mathcal{P}, \ \displaystyle\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} A_i \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
Thus, $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra by definition.
Please can you help me prove that $\forall A \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega), A \in \mathcal{F}$.

The statement is false.
A sample space $\Omega$ can have many sigma-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ (and also a "measurable space" $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ can have many probability measures $\mathbb{P}$).
For example, $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ is a sigma-algebra.
Or, if $\emptyset\subset A\subset \Omega$, then $\{\emptyset, A, A^c, \Omega\}$ is also a sigma-algebra.
And indeed, $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a sigma-algebra.
(In elementary probability, it may not often be important to consider sigma-algebras other than $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, in the case where $\Omega$ is finite or countable. Later, we often want to consider multiple sigma-algebras on the same sample space. For example for a process evolving in time, we might consider "filtrations" $\mathcal{F}_1\subseteq\mathcal{F}_2\subseteq\mathcal{F}_3\subseteq\dots\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ where the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_n$ might represent  something like "information observable at time $n$".)

Thank you for clearing this up for me! :)
